# JsPlumb при горизонтальном скролле не перерисовывает связи

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Делаю связи между блоками во Vue с помощью JsPlumb (2.15.6).
Появилась проблема с горизонтальным скроллингом и перерисовкой связей (см.гифку)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особенность заключается в том, что горизонтальный скроллинг не всей страницы, а внутреннего div-элемента (с помощью css `overflow-x: scroll`)
Код инициализации:

```js
// свойства
defaultJsPlumbSettings: {
        Connector: ['Flowchart', {
          alwaysRespectStubs: true,
          midpoint: 0.2,
          stub: [10, 15],
          cornerRadius: 20
        } ],
        PaintStyle: {
          stroke: 'gray',
          strokeWidth: 2
        },
        EndpointStyles: [{ fill: 'gray' }, { fill: 'gray' }],
        HoverPaintStyle: { stroke: 'red' },
        EndpointHoverStyle: { fill: 'red' }
      }
// инициализация
jsPlumb.ready(() => {
      const usergroup_graph = this.$refs.usergroup_graph;
      const jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
        ...this.defaultJsPlumbSettings
      });

      jsPlumbInstance.setContainer(usergroup_graph);

      jsPlumbInstance.connect({
        source: el_1,
        target: el_2,
        ...
      });
})
```

Эту проблему решат данный функционал:

```
usergroup_graph.onscroll = () => { jsPlumbInstance.repaintEverything() };
```

но при таком подходе перерисовка происходит с некоторой задержкой и явно не считается грамотным решением.
К примеру, если вовсе не указывать `jsPlumbInstance.setContainer`, то при горизонтальном скроллинге такой проблемы нет, но без указания контейнера связи смещаются и не имеют относительных координат

Comment: Оберните контейнер со связями в ещё один div и скрольте его

Comment: @Talleyran к сожалению проблема осталась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как предложил в комментариях @Talleyran необходимо обернуть контейнер в еще один div-блок и уже на него вешать css `overflow-x: scroll`, но это может не сработать если не указать так-же css `position: relative;` как для блока-обертки так и для самого контейнера.
Решение:

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <div style="position: relative;" ref="usergroup_graph">
```